# Creating an exe - file for data exchange with server in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I am completely lost and I do not know how to approach the following problem which my boss assigned to me.

I have to create an exe - file containing a code which works as follows when I run it: It sends a certain file, say file_A, to a server. When the server receives this file it sends back a json-file, say file_B, which contains an url. More precisely, the attribute of the json-file contains the url. The code should then open the url in a browser.

And here are the details:

The above code (one version in tcl) must accept three parameters and a fourth optional parameter (so, it is not necessary to pass a fourth parameter). The three parameters are: server, type and file.

**server**: this is the path to the server. For example, https://localhost:0008.

**type**: this is the type of the file (file_A) to be send to the server: xdt / png

**file**: this is the path to the file (file_A) to be send to the server.

The fourth optional parameter is:

**wksName**: if this paramater is given, then the url should be opened with it in the browser.

I got an example code for the above procedure written in python. It should serve as an orientation. I do not know anything about this language but to a large extend I understand the code. It looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import platform
import sys
import webbrowser
import requests

args_dict = {}
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
   if '=' in arg:
    sep = arg.find('=')
    key, value = arg[:sep], arg[sep + 1:]
    args_dict[key] = value

server = args_dict.get('server', 'http://localhost:0008')
request_url = server + '/NAME_List_number'
type = args_dict.get('type', 'xdt')
file = args_dict.get('file', 'xdtExamples/xdtExample.gdt')
wksName = args_dict.get('wksName', platform.node())

try:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        try:
            r = requests.post(request_url, data={'type': type}, files={'file': f})
            request_url = r.json()['url'] + '?wksName=' + wksName
            webbrowser.open(url = request_url, new = 2)

        except Exception as e:
        print('Error:', e)
        print('Request url:', request_url)
except:
    print('File \'' + file + '\' not found')
```

As you can see, the crucial part of the above code is this:

```
try:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        try:
            r = requests.post(request_url, data={'type': type}, files={'file': f})
            request_url = r.json()['url'] + '?wksName=' + wksName
            webbrowser.open(url = request_url, new = 2)

        except Exception as e:
        print('Error:', e)
        print('Request url:', request_url)
except:
    print('File \'' + file + '\' not found')
```

Everything else above it are just definitions. If possible, I would like to translate the above code into tcl. Could you please help me with this issue?

It doesn't have to be a 1-1 "tcl-translation" as long as it works as described above, and hopefully as simple as the above one.

I am not familiar with concepts such as sending/receiving data to/from servers, reading json-files etc.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You could start with the relevant pages in the Tcl Wiki: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/http and https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/JSON .

Comment: For converting the Tcl script to a self-contained .exe there are a number of methods available, but one I have used successfully is http://www.ch-werner.de/cgi-bin/luck.pl .

Comment: `localhost:0008` seems unlikely; a typo maybe for `localhost:8000`?

Comment: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/File+Upload+with+tcl%27s+http looks relevant for the request building.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I took a look at the above links and they turned out to be very helpful. Thanks again!